# Is there a way to make Firefox smart bar forget preferences?

Tags: firefox

Do you know of any way to clear the preferences that the smart bar has learned? Say, if you have 5 matches for a particular word, it learns which one you most go to and puts that first in the list. I know you can kind of re-train it to choose a different entry, but is there a way to make it forget all the things it has learned at one time?

I don't mean deleting the browsing history or anything like that, just starting afresh about which items in results I prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hover over any entry you want to get rid of and hit Delete

Comment: Well, actually, I'm wanting to delete all of them. That would take a long time, but thanks. Also, will they be allowed to come back if you delete them this way?

Comment: "will they be allowed to come back if you delete them this way?" but of course.

Comment: Marked as answer because this was the best/closest way. Thanks.

Comment: you're quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

tried 'clear private history'? one of the options there is 'browsing and download history' which should do the trick

Comment: Well, see, here's the subtle difference. I don't want to clear my download or browsing history, just the preferences about which one I prefer in the results.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the Firefox smart bar from suggesting anything but your bookmarks, go to Tools > Options > Privacy and set the Location Bar to only display bookmarks.  I think this is what you want to do.  If you want to get your suggestions back, just go back to the option and tell it to display history and bookmarks.